# how to set custom xkb_keymap in nixos

Tags: nixos

I have following layout `layouts/en_ru`

```
xkb_keymap {
  xkb_keycodes      { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
  xkb_geometry      { include "pc(pc104)" };
  xkb_types         { include "complete" };
  xkb_compat        { include "complete" };

  xkb_symbols {
    include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)"
    include "group(rctrl_rshift_toggle)"
    include "capslock(swapescape)"

    // swap right alt and left control
    replace key <RALT> { [ Control_L ] };
    modifier_map Control { <RALT> };

    // swap ; and : only in us layout
    replace key <AC10> { [ colon, semicolon ],
                        [ Cyrillic_zhe, Cyrillic_ZHE ] };

    // helpers //
    // xinput list
    // xinput test 16
    // xkbcomp $DISPLAY out.xkb
    // cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
  };
};
```

[which is loaded in](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/dotfiles/blob/master/xinitrc#L16) `$HOME/xinitrc` like this

```
xkbcomp $HOME/.config/layouts/en_ru $DISPLAY
```

How to move all this to `configuration.nix`?

---

I have made first part of this happen by adding

```
xserver = {
  enable = true;
  layout = "us,ru";
  xkbOptions = "caps:swapescape,grp:rctrl_rshift_toggle";
};
```

to my `configuration.nix`, but I don't know how to add this part and make it system wide

```
// swap right alt and left control
replace key <RALT> { [ Control_L ] };
modifier_map Control { <RALT> };

// swap ; and : only in us layout
replace key <AC10> { [ colon, semicolon ],
                    [ Cyrillic_zhe, Cyrillic_ZHE ] };
```

Comment: my first thought is that your swap-Ralt-Lctrl portion is a fairly simple new option to create.  the swap-in-us-layout is less so.  if altering the system xkb database on nixos is like most linuxes, here's how to make a new option: https://askubuntu.com/a/969232/669043 ... but i suspect it's a little more like implementing that sort of change as a local patch to a source package that then gets compiled for your particular system, and that's beyond my experience.  if you can figure that out, you'd just add your new option to your `xkbOptions` line like any other option.

Comment: the swap-in-us-layout probably would need to be added as a separate variant (theoretically it could simply `include us` and then do your `replace key` -- without the cyrillic symbols -- see `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` for examples).  then instead of `layout = "us,ru"` you'd specify `layout = "us-myvariant,ru"`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a temporary issue. A fix is in systemd, but the version of systemd isn't in NixOS yet:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/5016eb56352a7ea1f61ea106fa4f5639fbf6ddd8

I know what you're saying! "That's not an answer!" and I agree! Luckily, we have the option `services.udev.extraHwdb`, where we can add our own udev rules in `configuartion.nix`.

Here's the final fix that I have working now:

```
services.udev.extraHwdb = ''
  evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnPurism*:pn*Librem13v4*:pvr*
    KEYBOARD_KEY_56=backslash
''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      sessionCommands = ''
        ${xorg.xkbcomp}/bin/xkbcomp ${layout} $DISPLAY &
      '';
    };
```

https://github.com/srghma/dotfiles/blob/0054e4586183e0dcf1bdecc9507bde937c365f30/nixos/root/services/default.nix#L116